# La función fitdist para una distribución lamnda generalizada arroja el error: Error in manageparam

Tags: base-de-datos, r

Tengo mi código:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(MASS)
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)  
library(actuar) 
library(e1071) 
library(FAdist)
library(gld)

archivos <- c("2014_1.csv",
              "2014_2.csv",
              "2014_3.csv",
              "2014_4.csv",
              "2015_1.csv",
              "2015_2.csv",
              "2015_3.csv",
              "2015_4.csv",
              "2016_1.csv",
              "2016_2.csv",
              "2016_3.csv",
              "2016_4.csv",
              "2017_1.csv",
              "2017_2.csv",
              "2017_3.csv",
              "2017_4.csv",
              "2018_1.csv",
              "2018_2.csv",
              "2018_3.csv",
              "2018_4.csv",
              "2019_1.csv")

lista_df <- lapply(archivos, function (x) read.table(x, sep=";",header=T))
df_unido <- reduce(rbind, lista_df) 

df_unido_n <- df_unido %>% 
    dplyr::select(NombreCentral,POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH,CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2) %>%
    filter(POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH >0,!is.na(POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH) , CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2 >0, !is.na(CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2))

#cuando quieras guardar como csv una tabla
write_csv(df_unido_n,"dfgaby.csv")

nombres= df_unido_n$NombreCentral
nombres.factor=factor(nombres)
nmb=levels(nombres.factor)
length(nmb)

lista_total= list()
for (i in 1:44){
    dfn=df_unido_n %>%
        filter(NombreCentral == nmb[i])
    lista_total[[i]]<-dfn
}

ggplot(lista_total[[24]], aes(x = CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2)) + geom_density()
ggplot(lista_total[[24]], aes(lista_total[[24]]$CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1.2)
ggplot(lista_total[[24]], aes(lista_total[[24]]$CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2)) + stat_ecdf(geom = "point", size=1) + ggtitle("CDF GRAPHIC")
ggplot(lista_total[[24]], aes(x = CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), binwidth=1, colour="black", fill="white") + geom_density(alpha=0.2, size=0.4) + ggtitle("DENSITY AND HISTOGRAM GRAPHIC")
quan <- quantile(lista_total[[24]]$CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2, probs = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1))


col_prueba=lista_total[[24]]$CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2
col_prueba_aux=(lista_total[[24]]$CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2)/10^4
str(col_prueba)
summary(col_prueba)
plotdist(col_prueba, histo=TRUE, demp=TRUE)
descdist(col_prueba)
fw2_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "weibull")
fw3_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "weibull3", start = list(shape = 1, scale = 1)) 
fg_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "gamma")
fln_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "lnorm")
fex_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "exp")
fgm_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "gumbel", start=list(scale=50, location=50))
fn_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "norm")
fll_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "llogis", start = list(shape = 1, scale = 1))
fl_p <- fitdist(col_prueba, "logis")
```

Al llegar aquí, busco generar un fitdist para una distribución lamnda generalizada y encontre el siguiente código que permitia modelarla en R (la dificultad de esta distribución esta en la cantidad de parametros necesarios para modelarla, la librería gld me da las herramientas de este código)

```
fitGLD <- fit.fkml(col_prueba_aux, method = "ML")
optGLD <- fitGLD$optim.results$par
opt <- round(optGLD ,1)
```

Las 3 líneas anteriores funcionan, pero al ejecutar la siguiente linea:

```
fgl_p<- fitdist(col_prueba_aux, "gl", start=list(opt[1], opt[2], opt[3], opt[4]), method="mle", control=list(trace=0, REPORT=1))
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

**Error in manageparam(start.arg = start, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,  : 
Starting values must be a named list (or a function returning a named list).**

Y pensé qué con creando una lista nueva con los elementos de la variable opt y escalando la base de datos (esta función es sensible a valores altos, cree una variable auxiliar en la que escale mis datos, más arriba) se arreglaría, pero me sigue arrojando el mismo error, ayuda porfa.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot.legend<-c("Weibull","Weibull3","lnorm","gamma","exp","gumbel","norm","llogis","logis")
denscomp(list(fw2_p,fw3_p,fg_p,fln_p,fex_p,fgm_p,fn_p,fll_p,fl_p), plotstyle = "ggplot",legendtext = c("weibull-2P", "weibull-3P", "gamma", "lognormal", "exponential", "gumbel", "normal", "loglogistic", "logistic"))
cdfcomp(list(fw2_p,fw3_p,fg_p,fln_p,fex_p,fgm_p,fn_p,fll_p,fl_p), plotstyle = "ggplot",legendtext = c("weibull-2P", "weibull-3P", "gamma", "lognormal", "exponential", "gumbel", "normal", "loglogistic", "logistic"))
qqcomp(list(fw2_p,fw3_p,fg_p,fln_p,fex_p,fgm_p,fn_p,fll_p,fl_p), plotstyle = "ggplot",legendtext = c("weibull-2P", "weibull-3P", "gamma", "lognormal", "exponential", "gumbel", "normal", "loglogistic", "logistic"))
ppcomp(list(fw2_p,fw3_p,fg_p,fln_p,fex_p,fgm_p,fn_p,fll_p,fl_p), plotstyle = "ggplot",legendtext = c("weibull-2P", "weibull-3P", "gamma", "lognormal", "exponential", "gumbel", "normal", "loglogistic", "logistic"))
summary(fw2_p)
summary(fw3_p)
summary(fg_p)
summary(fln_p)
summary(fex_p)
summary(fgm_p)
summary(fn_p)
summary(fll_p)
summary(fl_p)
gofstat(list(fw2_p,fw3_p,fg_p,fln_p,fex_p,fgm_p,fn_p,fll_p,fl_p))
bootdist(fw2_p)
bootdist(fw3_p)
bootdist(fg_p)
bootdist(fln_p)
bootdist(fex_p)
bootdist(fgm_p)
bootdist(fn_p)
bootdist(fll_p)
bootdist(fl_p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de empezar, te aclaro que no tengo ni idea de lo que estás queriendo hacer ni de lo que significa *"Fit Of Univariate Distributions To Non-Censored Data"*, pero lo que sí puedo decirte, es que el error:

> Error in manageparam(start.arg = start, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,
>   : **Starting values must be a named list** (or a function returning a
>   named list).

Te está diciendo que el parámetro `start` espera una lista con nombres, si vemos la documentación del parámetro `?fitdist`) confirmamos esto:

> **start**: A named list giving the initial values of parameters of the named distribution or a function of data computing initial values and
>   returning a named list. This argument may be omitted (default) for
>   some distributions for which reasonable starting values are computed
>   (see the 'details' section of mledist). It may not be into account for
>   closed-form formulas.

Y particularmente ¿qué nombres y qué valores?: **initial values of parameters of the named distribution**, es decir los parámetros iniciales de la función de distribución, en este caso estás usando `distr="gl"`, es decir una "Generalised Lambda Distribution", por lo que revisando la documentación (`?dgl`):

```
dgl(x, lambda1 = 0, lambda2 = NULL, lambda3 = NULL, lambda4 = NULL, 
  param = "fkml", lambda5 = NULL, inverse.eps = .Machine$double.eps,
  max.iterations = 500)
```

Observamos que los nombres que deberías pasar son los de `lambda1, lambda2, lambda3, lambda4`, es decir:

```
fgl_p <- fitdist(col_prueba_aux, 
                 "gl", 
                 start=list(lambda1 = opt[1], lambda2 = opt[2], lambda3 = opt[3], lambda2 = opt[4]), 
                 method="mle", 
                 control=list(trace=0, REPORT=1)
                 )
```

Comentarios finales:

- La lista `start` obviamente modificará los parámetros en función de la distribución elegida. Por ejemplo en el caso de una normal, dónde los parámetros son la media (`mean`) y la desviación estándar (`sd`), la lista sería:

  ```
  fitdist(col_prueba_aux,  
          "norm",         
          start=list(mean=10, sd=1), 
          method="mle", 
          control=list(trace=0, REPORT=1))
  ```
- He visto algunos ejemplos en la red en los que no se usan nombre, seguramente en algún momento los parámetros se pasaban posicionalmente a la función distribución, con la versión actual evidentemente ya no es posible

Comment: Ya ya, gracias, no había visto lo del los nombres, pero aun así me arroja un par de advertencias, aunque ya me reconoce el fitdist fgl_p